# UBUNTU 15.10 BLACK SCREEN AFTER SUSPEND Acer Aspire

Tags: nvidia, suspend

I am using an Acer Aspire V15 with nvidia 840m dedicated graphics card. Everytime I shut or suspend my laptop and try to wake it up the screen light turns on but the screen remains black with a white - blinking in the corner.
I have tried

- Locking laptop then suspending
- turning light locker off
- manual suspend in terminal

  I have seen this question asked in other places but no answer has worked for me. Hopefully someone with similar conditions can help solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Linux Mint and I had similar problems (not exactly the same). Bit of searching showed that it is related to the graphics card. This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkKkuzWlaGo) helped. Try to install the drivers from xorg package.

PS - In my case, the laptop woke with blank screen if it had gone to suspension because I had closed the screen (the configuration in Power settings was - closing of the screen makes the laptop go to suspension). I removed that setting. Now, when I press the on/off button, the laptop sleeps/wakes. And it has been working fine as of now. So, in my case, going to suspension by closing the screen was the problem. Not sure whether it is the same for you. (I had Intel graphics card)

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Xubuntu) on Acer Aspire E15. The issue seemed to be with light-locker and opening/closing the computer lid. The following worked for me:

```
$ sudo sed -i -e 's/IgnoreLid=false/IgnoreLid=true/g' /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge -y light-locker light-locker-settings
$ reboot
```

This solution only works if you use light-locker, not gdm3